# 4 Divs that would have to be aligned in the following format with django templates

Tags: django, django-templates

There are 4 divs in that would have to be aligned in the following format with django templates

```
Div 1 : Div 3
Div 2 : Div 4
```

These DIVs are in the for loop. How would you split them.

The template is so far is a basic for loop. I do pass along with total number of divs to be displayed:

```
{% for item in items %}
     {{ item.totalcount }} <-- 4   
     {{ item }}
     {{ forloop.counter }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you post the template code you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`forloop.counter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for) in some way, like this:

```
{% for x in some_collection %}
{% if forloop.counter < half_of_collection_count %}
<div style="float:left;">
{%else%}
<div style="margin-left:200px;">
{%endif%}
    content
</div>
```

Of course, you'll have to change the style of the diff according to your needs.

Hope this helps!

Comment: TemplateSyntaxError
Could not parse the remainder: '/' from '/'